# How can I downgrade Firebase version?

Tags: firebase, npm

I have installed Firebase version 8.6.5 using `npm install firebase`. But I wish to downgrade Firebase to version 7.16.1 due to some code compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

Just run:

```
npm i -S firebase@^7.16.1
```

This is the local Firebase package you use in your project and we use `-S` to make sure we save it in our `package.json`. It is recommended to save all packages you use in your project. `i -S` is just a shortcut for `install --save`.

For your Firebase Tools you use in the console it would be `npm i -g firebase-tools@version-number`

Comment: What is i -S means?

Comment: oh it actually same as `npm install --save` but why need to save? Why this get more upvote? i think https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569259/2465827 (the other answer) looks better.

Comment: There is no need to uninstall if you install another version. We need the save so you have that version memorised in case you clear your project or need to delete node_modules or clone it on another device.

Comment: I think `npm i -S firebase@^7.16.1` and `npm i -S firebase-tools@^7.16.1` are different packages. And using ^ make it the highest version ?

Answer (score 4):

Just run:

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

npm install -g firebase-tools@7.16.1
```